# Docker: Can a secret created and deleted in a single RUN command be recovered from the resulting image?

Tags: docker, docker-build

I want to use some secret keys during my docker building process. So I had the idea to inject these keys as build arguments into the building process. This should be safe. The [official documentation states](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg):

> Also, these values don’t persist in the intermediate or final images like ENV values do.

Here is an example of a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG key
...
RUN echo $key > /tmp/key && doSomethingWithKey && rm /tmp/key
...
```

As you can see, at one point I need to paste this key to a file. To make sure this key won't get "baked" into the final image I instantly remove the key.

Here's the build command:

```
$ docker build --build-arg key="secret" .
```

Now my question is: Is this safe or does the secret key get "stored" in the final image?

Comment: Personally, btw, I'd bind-mount the storage with the key in off the host as a shared volume.

Comment: As an aside -- `echo $key` is not the same as `echo "$key"`. The former will transform tabs and newlines to spaces, expand globs within the text, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy there isn't an option to bind mount a volume during a build, that is only valid for containers after you've built the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key won't be stored in the filesystem, but it will be stored in the layer metadata which you can see with a `docker history` on your image. Therefore I'd recommend against doing this.

I've seen this request most often with code checkouts from a private repo, where the login to that repo was being used in the build. If that's the case, you should instead checkout the code before the build command and then do a `COPY` of the checked out code from your Dockerfile.

Comment: Re: "won't be stored in the filesystem" -- what if the `devicemapper` driver is in use (storing block-level snapshots)? Wouldn't we still be storing deltas of any blocks that were modified in the creation and subsequent deletion of the file?

Comment: I believe by doing the steps in a single `RUN` you avoid having the data in one layer and deleted from another. Docker should only keep the result at the end of the `RUN`. Am I missing something specific to devicemapper?

Comment: Yes, you're missing something specific to devicemapper: Unlike aufs, overlay or overlay2, it's **block-level, not filesystem-level**. Thus, if anything is written to a block on the disk, it's stored unless the block itself is zeroed or overwritten, even if the file with an inode with that block in its map no longer exists.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't believe that would be accessible from inside the container. And from outside the container, as mentioned above, the data is visible in much easier methods than inspecting the block level data on the drive.

Comment: @BMitch, hmm. That's a fair point -- there's no obligation to expose the dm device to the container. I could definitely see cases where it would be *useful* (and at parity with "real" non-containerized systems) to have it exposed -- to permit containerized automated testing for fsck, undelete, or similar tools, for example -- but without reading the source have no idea whether the existence of such cases has influenced the relevant driver's design.

Answer (score 2):

A proven response: It does persist the secret value in the final image.

```
FROM alpine

ARG key
ARG securekey

RUN echo $key > /tmp/key
RUN echo $securekey > /tmp/securekey && rm /tmp/key


docker build . \
    --build-arg key=mykey-isnotsecure \
    --build-arg securekey=mykey-issecure -t test
```

Dumping the image with [`docker save`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/):

```
docker save test | strings | grep -o mykey............
```

Output:

```
mykey-isnotsecure
mykey-issecure","
mykey-isnotsecure
mykey-isnotsecure
mykey-issecure","
```

And as BMitch stated:

```
docker history --no-trunc test
IMAGE                                                                     CREATED             CREATED BY                                                                                                     SIZE                COMMENT
sha256:e013810c5be50cffa0d9b5e723ec548cdcc686d99efdf792b2bda90baa0795c8   3 hours ago         |2 key=mykey-isnotsecure securekey=mykey-issecure /bin/sh -c echo $securekey > /tmp/securekey && rm /tmp/key   15 B
sha256:cabafd664056bc90ea9d71fafcdb65e4abe3d98a66c75066218fcf9a88962ba1   3 hours ago         |2 key=mykey-isnotsecure securekey=mykey-issecure /bin/sh -c echo $key > /tmp/key                              18 B
sha256:699ff2abecb92b13169a669d99c64fcc19c8d44590778c7b7ee944559208e81a   3 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG securekey                                                                               0 B
sha256:26aaa6f92951accc5cb21a13900f9cabee58f65119ffb0eb4b546c3ea19b3ce1   3 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG key                                                                                     0 B
sha256:a41a7446062d197dd4b21b38122dcc7b2399deb0750c4110925a7dd37c80f118   4 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]                                                                             0 B
<missing>                                                                 4 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:ce33aabbc5f370e58ebe911e081ce093e3df18d689c2d5a5d092c77973f62a54 in /               3.97 MB
```

---

Edit. Disclaimer about the [Time Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270241/docker-can-a-secret-created-and-deleted-in-a-single-run-command-be-recovered-fr/44270307#comment75549176_44270497) event.

On my Mac:

```
▶ date
Tue May 30 16:45:39 ART 2017
```

My containers are 3 hours shift (ART vs UTC):

```
~
▶ docker run ubuntu date
Tue May 30 16:27:29 UTC 2017
```

ART == UTC-3

Comment: You ran your test 3 hours before the question was asked? Now I know where the TARDIS went! :)

Comment: I challenge you to discover/guess `why` *3 hours ago...*

Comment: Thanks, I didn't noticed it. It seems that it's related to laptop after sleep https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/17

Comment: Yeah, sleeping a mac will throw off those timestamps. But I'm still going with TARDIS thief. :)